# Prove that if $p > 0$, then there exists a constant $C_p$ such that for $x>0$, $x^p \leq C_pe^x$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $p > 0$, then there exists a constant $C_p$ such that for $x>0$, $x^p \leq C_pe^x$.

I think I use the derivative of $x^pe^{-x}$ but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Find an integer $n \ge p$,
so $x^p \le x^n$.
From the power series for $e^x$,
$e^x > \frac{x^n}{n!}$,
so $x^n < n! e^x$
so
$x^p \le x^n
<n! e^x
< (\lfloor p \rfloor+1)! e^x
$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
(x^p e^{-x})'=x^{p-1}e^{-x}(p-x)
$$

Therefore, when $p=x$, it hits the maximum $M$. Take $ M\le C_p$, you et the answer. It's quite easy. Do I miss something?